# does this result require constant ambient density?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, acoustics, ideal-gas, differential-equations

I'm posting from my phone, so I can't make this  very snazy.  My question pertains to the equation following *"The derivative of density may in turn be eliminated by using the mass conservation relation, Eq. (25),"* from the essay found here:

https://www.whoi.edu/science/PO/people/jprice/class/ELreps.pdf

And captured in the following:

[image]

[image]

Is the only way to remove the partial of $\rho_o\left(\alpha\right)$ with respect to $\alpha$ in the derivative of Eq. 25 to assume the ambient density is constant?

Equation (25) is:

$$\rho_o(a)(\frac{\partial \xi}{\partial a})^{-1}=\rho(a,t)$$

The text later states: *"The derivative of density may in turn be eliminated by using the mass conservation relation, Eq. (25),"*

$$\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial\alpha}=-\rho_{o}\left(\frac{\partial^{2}\xi}{\partial a^{2}}\right)/\left(\frac{\partial^{2}\xi}{\partial a^{2}}\right)^{2}.$$

In general, that derivative will be

$$\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial\alpha}=\frac{\partial\rho_{o}}{\partial a}\left(\frac{\partial\xi}{\partial a}\right){}^{-1}-\rho_{o}\left(\frac{\partial^{2}\xi}{\partial a^{2}}\right)/\left(\frac{\partial^{2}\xi}{\partial a^{2}}\right)^{2}.$$

That is, somehow the author has eliminated $\frac{\partial\rho_{o}}{\partial a}\left(\frac{\partial\xi}{\partial a}\right){}^{-1}$ from the derivative.  The only way I can see to do that is to assume $\frac{\partial\rho_{o}}{\partial a}=0,$ which is equivalent to saying the ambient (or nominal) density is a constant function of position.

Is there another way to eliminate this term?

Comment: I think the answer to your question is "no."  $\rho_0$ seems to be the mass per unit length at time zero at the material point situated at position $\alpha$, and the parameter $\xi(\alpha,t)$ is the position at time t of the material point that was at position $\alpha$ at time zero.

Comment: Your observation about $\rho_o\left(\alpha\right)$ is correct. But we are differentiating with respect to $\alpha$.  The Leibniz product rule will, in general, result in the sum of two terms.  The equation in the text has only one term on the right hand side.  The only way I can see to make that happen is for $\rho_o\left(\alpha\right)$ to be constant.

Comment: I really don't understand what you are saying.

Comment: The right-hand side of Eq. (25) is the product of two values.  Both of which depend on $\alpha$.  Differentiation with respect to $\alpha$ will result in the sum of two terms, unless there is some means of eliminating one of them.  If $\rho_o$ is not a constant function of $\alpha$, then that variation in density with position will contribute to the value of $\rho$ at a later time.

Comment: I'm going to add an answer which I hope will explain Eqn. 25 better.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a rope with variable mass per unit length $\rho$ along its length.  We are going to perform some kind of local stretching and/or compression along the rope, and we want to quantify how the changes in linear density are related to the stretching we impose.

To quantify the kinematics of the deformation, we are going to label the various cross sections of the rope by their axial spatial locations "a" at time t = 0. These labels become permanent markers for the cross sections.  At later times t during the deformation, the spatial locations of the various cross sections $\xi$ are expressed as functions of time and of their marker labels by $\xi=\xi(a,t)$.  So at time t, the distance between two adjacent cross sections that were at a and a + da at time zero are now at $\xi(a,t)$ and $\xi(a+da,t)=\xi(a,t)+\frac{\partial \xi}{\partial a}da$.  So the distance between the two cross sections at time t is now $d\xi=\frac{\partial \xi}{\partial a}da$.

In order for mass to be conserved over each interval along the length of the rope during the deformation, we must have that $$\rho(a,0)da=\rho(a,t)d\xi=\rho(a,t)\frac{\partial \xi}{\partial a}da$$or$$\rho(a,0)=\rho(a,t)\frac{\partial \xi}{\partial a}$$
I hope this helps.

Comment: That explains the origin of Eq. (25), but I'm not sure how it addresses my question.  I'm asking about the derivative of  $\rho(a,0)=\rho(a,t)\frac{\partial \xi}{\partial a}.$ I will try to improve my original post in the short period that I have access to a computer with Internet connectivity.